# MySQL : Create custom data directory withtout Perl

Tags: mysql

MySQL provides a script for initialiazing a new data directory for databases storage.

Unfortunately, on the noinstall zip for Windows, it is only a Perl script.

I'd like to initialize a new data directory without using Perl, since I'm building an auto-install to be launched from several machines and I want to reduce the softwares installation duty.

Is there a workaround for this script that does not require to have Perl installed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated [on the MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-data-directories.html), you can just copy the `data` dir from the MySQL zip wherever you want.

Then you will just need either launch `mysqld` using the `--datadir=new_path` option, or specify `datadir=new_path` in the `my.ini`/`my.cnf` you'll be using.